# Foundation 4 / IE 7/8 incompatibility list

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, zurb-foundation

I'm starting a new project with foundation and the scope demands limited support for older browsers (including ie7 - 9). As I'll be working with Zurb's Foundation 4 Framework and they don't (fully) support IE 8 and below I'm currently looking for a list of Foundation 4 Features that don't work in those older browsers.

I know that the media queries are a problem but I think I can fix that easily and I'm currently not looking for specific fixes and polyfills but a list of not or only partly supported features (both css and js).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the docs or look at the "kitchen sink" in your respective browser. I believe ie8 might be stuck with the mobile grid which may or may not be a good thing for your use case. If you want better backwards compatibility with ie, I suggest using foundation 3, unless there is a specific feature you must have that is f4 specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind upgrading to Foundation 5, you can try some polyfills:
http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/241-foundation-5-and-ie8